# How to mock require('child_process').fork(__dirname + '/worker') using jasmine

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine-node

How to mock const

     **Source :**

```
 child = require('child_process').fork('/worker'); // using jasmine
```

There are some package for mocking spawn task

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mock-require` to mock any module, including `child_process`. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require

You'll need to provide an object with properties that you need. You didn't specify what you need so it's hard to be more specific but for example you may need to provide a mocked stdout stream or something like that and you can prepare that in the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Fine answer for mine

```
var events = require('events');

var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
var messagehandle = function (message, callback) {

    if (message.action == 'init')
        callback('init complete');
}

eventEmitter.addListener('message', messagehandle);
eventEmitter.send = function (message) {
    eventEmitter.emit('message', message, message.cb);
} 
var mockprocess = {
    fork: function (path) {
        return eventEmitter;
    }
};

mock('child_process', mockprocess);
```